# rsync doesn't delete files in destination directory

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

The following `rsync` command does not delete files in destination directory

```
rsync -avr --delete hulio@192.168.255.42:/home/hulio/hotspots_test/* /home/zsumo/hotpoint/data
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the command, is that it includes * in `hotspots_test/*`

The command `rsync --delete` doesn't work with wildcard entries

[rsync man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

> **--delete**
>
> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side
>   (ones that aren't on the sending side), but only for the directories
>   that are being synchronized. You must have asked rsync to send the
>   whole directory (e.g. lqdirrq or lqdir/rq) **without using a wildcard
>   for the directory's contents (e.g. lqdir/*rq) since the wildcard is
>   expanded by the shell and rsync thus gets a request to transfer
>   individual files, not the files' parent directory**. Files that are
>   excluded from the transfer are also excluded from being deleted unless
>   you use the --delete-excluded option or mark the rules as only
>   matching on the sending side (see the include/exclude modifiers in the
>   FILTER RULES section).