# Why does this rsync command not delete files in destination directory

Tags: linux-mint, rsync

```
rsync -av --del ~/ /media/m/USB\ Stick/kopia/rsynclinux/
```

For reasons unknown I was living in a false impression that once I remove a file from home directory in source the file would be removed in destination as well.

I had to reinstall and restore the backup... only to find how wrong I was. I now have an incredible mess of obsolete & duplicated files!!

Well I won't travel back to the past to make a proper backup, instead I'm stuck with slowly, ardously bringing order to my old notes.

But at least I want to avoid such mistakes in the future. Why does this call to `rsync` fail to delete files?

Note I read this: [rsync doesn't delete files in destination directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354796/rsync-doesnt-delete-files-in-destination-directory) But as U can see my call to `rsync` does not include a wildcard so the two problems are not the same

Answer (score 1):

The `--del` option is an alias for `--delete-during`. The option you were looking for is `--delete`.

There's a good summary of the different options at https://superuser.com/questions/156664/what-are-the-differences-between-the-rsync-delete-options.

Comment: The `--delete-during` (i.e. `--del`) implies `--delete`, and has done since it was first [added in 2.6.4](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS) (30 March 2005)

Answer (score 0):

If `/media/m/USB\ Stick/kopia/rsynclinux/` is a FAT-based or NTFS filesystem it cannot store all the attributes (metadata) for files copied from a native-Linux filesystem. This will trigger `rsync` into considering there has been an error copying the files, and the `--delete` will be disabled.

From the documentation, `man rsync`, under `--delete` (implied by `--del` or `--delete-during`):

> If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled.